# Guardian not working in Gazebo

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to study the guardian-ros-pkg to learn more about ros, controlling a skid steer 4 wheel robot, and SLAM. I have installed the package from source and now I'm trying to run a simulation in gazebo following the instructions found [here](http://code.google.com/p/guardian-ros-pkg/wiki/guardian_simulation_guide).

First, I cannot teleop the robot properly using the teleop_keyboard node. Q and E work, causing the robot to rotate in place around the Z axis (yaw), but WASD do not cause the robot to translate. Pressing or holding Shift makes no difference.

Second, when I try to run the SLAM algorithm for navigation, the robot just rotates in place endlessly and never explores the space. It should look like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5QNqhAAnm8).

When I launch with guardian_robotnik.launch, all of the models load just fine, but I get an error: [FATAL] [1343077767.457597153, 0.712000000]: GuardianController

I also get this warning: [ WARN] [1343077768.818456569, 0.726000000]: multiple inconsistent  exists due to fixed joint reduction, overwriting previous value [false] with [true].

Third, when I try to launch rviz to view the map generated by SLAM, I get several erros and a seg fault, but I have never had a problem opening rviz before.

```
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0x8010, next=0x8023
OpenGL Warning: glXCreatePbuffer not implemented by Chromium
[ERROR] [1343074659.579961264, 41.872000000]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create Pbuffer in GLXPBuffer::GLXPBuffer at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXRenderTexture.cpp (line 137)
```

Running Electric on Ubuntu 11.10 guest, OS X 10.7.4 host with 3D acceleration enabled for the guest.

Have I just missed a step, or is something wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39576/guardian-not-working-in-gazebo/) by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you should ask to the company Robotnik directly

[www.robotnik.es/en/contact](http://www.robotnik.es/en/contact/)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0